# Retrieve nested data list from angularfire2 5.0.0-rc.2

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic3

I want to display list of objects from the Firebase to the Ionic view using angularfire2 5.0.0-rc.2.

**This is my list of objects from the Firebase**

[image: this is my list of objects from the Firebase]

**This is the method from the service, used to retrieve all the data related to Restaurants**

```
getRestaurants() {
    this.restaurants = this.af.list('/Restaurants')
    return this.restaurants;
}
```

**This the component where I accept data from the service**

```
 export class RestaurantsPage {

  restaurants: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public af: AngularFireDatabase, public dataservice: handleDataService) {
    this.dataservice.getUserEmail().subscribe(res => {
      this.restaurants = this.dataservice.getRestaurants().valueChanges();
    })
    // this.items.subscribe(res => console.log(res[0].$key));
 }
```

**And this is the HTML page which I want to display my data**

```
<ion-content class="card-background-page">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let restaurant of restaurants | async">
      <ion-thumbnail item-start>
        <img src="img/thumbnail-totoro.png">
      </ion-thumbnail>
      <h2>{{restaurant.Name}}</h2>
      <h3>{{restaurant.Description}}</h3>
      <button ion-button clear item-end (click)="gotoPage(restaurant)">View</button>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

And i know in the service method i have done nothing but just returned the value getting form the Firebase API. What i want is to know how could i iterate through the keys inside **s@g,com** and show the data inside each key in my HTML page as a list. I have tried it using map operator as well, but i couldn't find a better solution in angularfire2 5.0.0-rc.2.

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found these links helpful for anybody who has the same problem

Updating FirebaseListObservable to AngularFireList
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md

Retrieving data as lists
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md

And this is the way that i have done it

**This is my service**

```
    getRestaurants() {
    let restaurants = this.af.list('/Restaurants');
    return restaurants;
}

getResturantsFromKeys(key){
    let rest = this.af.list('/Restaurants/'+ key);
    return rest;
}
```

**And this is my component**

```
  restaurants: any[] = [];
  allRestaurants: Observable<any[]>
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public af: AngularFireDatabase, public dataservice: handleDataService) {
    this.dataservice.getUserEmail().subscribe(res => {
      this.dataservice.getRestaurants().snapshotChanges().subscribe(actions => {
        actions.forEach(action => {
          // console.log(action.payload.val());
          this.allRestaurants = this.dataservice.getResturantsFromKeys(action.key).valueChanges();
          this.allRestaurants.subscribe(res => {
            res.forEach(element => {
              this.restaurants.push(element);
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

**And HTML file looks like this**

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let restaurant of restaurants">
  <h2>{{restaurant.Name}}</h2>
  <h3>{{restaurant.Description}}</h3>
  <button ion-button clear item-end (click)="gotoPage(restaurant)">View</button>
</ion-item>
```

May be there will be a better and easy answer than this one. But this is how i get through the problem.